# iOS memory leak on initializeBufferWithCopyOfBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I found a memory leak when i download image, but i never found any cycles retain on it??

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

the code:

```
class DetailVCHeaderPictuerScrollViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    ...
    var item: DetailVCHeaderPictuerScrollViewCellItem! {
        didSet {
            var ip = indexPath

            // memory was leak on the follow line
            DownloadImgOnMain(item.img, { [weak self](img, finished) -> Void in
                if self == nil { return }
                if ip == self?.indexPath {
                    self?.imageV.image = img
                }
            })
        }
    }
    ...
}

func DownloadImgOnMain(url: String, callback: (img: UIImage?, finished: Bool)->Void) {
    SDWebImageDownloader
    .sharedDownloader()
    .downloadImageWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!,
        options: SDWebImageDownloaderOptions.allZeros,
        progress: nil) { (img, data, err, finished) -> Void in

        DispatchBlockOnMainSafe({ () -> Void in
           callback(img: img, finished: finished)
        })
    }
}

func DispatchBlockOnMainSafe(b: () -> Void) {
    if NSThread.isMainThread() {
        b()
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), b)
    }
}
```

Or was it the system framework problem? or the language problem?